# Getting a reference to a React Component using useRef hook

Tags: reactjs, reference, react-hooks

The current value in the reference object that useRef returns is always null.

I've reproduced the issue here
https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-field-hmusg

I want to get a reference to the component `<MyComponent/>`

Comment: Hey, let me know if the solution below works for you :)

Comment: Yeah, it worked... I wonder why the usage of useRef is not clear in the documentation of react. Also the solution indeed gives a ref to the root div. But what I want to actually do using ref is access child component state variable. How can I do that?

Comment: Oh you never mentioned any usage of state in your code so I figured that was all your question was. Sure, I can show you how to get those methods as well.

Comment: Oh sorry, in fact that was my intent of accessing the ref, in stateful component, we accessed child component state through ref.state.childState. Right?

Comment: No worries, yes that is correct, you would be able to do that for a stateful class component. It's a bit trickier for functional components however. I've updated the code and sandbox below. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Cool, just wrote out the explanation, let me know if that makes sense. Also, please do consider marking as solution :)

Comment: Thanks it worked. This way of accessing states feel more like using access specifiers in Java where you need to explicitly specify what you expose to the outside world.

Comment: I'm pretty sure thats where the inspiration behind hooks came from :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You actually need to use the `forwardRef` method when dealing with functional components. Additionally, there is not a particular clean and easy way to retrieve the state-value of a functional-child component. But here is what you can do:

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useImperativeHandle } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const referenceToMyComponent = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          if (referenceToMyComponent.current) {
            console.log(referenceToMyComponent.current.returnStateValue());
          }
        }}
      >
        Print State reference
      </button>
      <MyComponent ref={referenceToMyComponent} />
    </div>
  );
}

const MyComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const returnStateValue = () => {
    return count;
  };

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      returnStateValue: returnStateValue
    };
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Counter: {count}</h4>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+1</button>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Essentially the key-points are the `forwardRef`, `useImperativeHandle`, and `returnStateValue`.

The `forwardRef` helps us pass a ref coming from a parent to the functional child-component.

The `useImperativeHandle` hook helps us bind the `ref` to the instance of the component, we still cannot extract the state-value from the child, but we can access functions defined in the child that would return the state-value anyway.

The `returnStateValue` function simply returns the state from inside the child-component. We can now access that function via our ref by using `referenceToMyComponent.current.returnStateValue()`

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-wiles-xst65

Comment: In my case it not working, I think because I have `Redux` in the middle. Any solution for that?